# retrieve custom exception message in calling method

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Intentionally i set email as null in DAO method.it goes to Exception block in persist method in DAO class where i put custom error message "Failed to add Employee" in Custom exception class;
How to catch that error message in controller.In Controller Exception block if i use e.getMessage() am getting whole message but i want only custom error message.

Calling method(controller)

---

```
try {                  
    employeeDao.persist(employees);
}  
catch (SpringUtilException ex) {    
    System.out.println("..at line 87......."+ex.getErrorMessage());
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Exception returned message: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Called method(DAO)

---

```
public void persist(Employees employee) throws SpringUtilException {
    try {
        employee.setEmail(null);
        em.persist(employee);
    } 
    catch (EntityExistsException e) {
        throw new SpringUtilException(e, "Employee Duplicate");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("at line 31 in DAO..");
        throw new SpringUtilException("Failed to add Employee"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: from where did you got the SpringUtilException?

Comment: What is displayed, what do you expect the program to display, and what's the code of SpringUtilException?

Comment: its normal Custom exception class.I found out that its not going any Exception blocks including Exception block in DAO method.i am confused where its going but in controller its coming in Exception block.

Comment: Even though am getting below error message in console but its not going into any error exception block in DAO method.am using JPA to insert data in database.[EL Fine]: 2012-06-20 15:42:54.661--ClientSession(18324508)--Connection(10989057)--INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, LAST_NAME, SALARY, CITY, STATE, ZIP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 bind => [277, null, ET, 2011-11-11, AD_VP, ETE, 11, null, null, null]
cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."EMPLOYEES"."EMAIL")

Comment: Stop catching exceptions in your controller, or at least call e.printStackTrace() on the exception, to know which exception is thrown. Then show us the stack trace. And getErrorMessage() is not a standard Exception method, so it's impossible to guess what it could do.

Comment: can you print the exception stacktrace? it may help.

Answer (score 0):

`em.persist()` just makes a transient entity persistent. It doesn't issue any insert statement.

The insert statement, which causes the exception you get, is issued at flush time. And the flush is done (in this case) at the end of the transaction, when the DAO method has already returned.

Don't rely on database constraints to validate your objects. Validate them explicitely, and don't even call `persist()` if the entity is invalid. The database constraints are a last resort check.

Comment: to test once again set employee as null and this time line 25 and 33 printed in the console.why its going into Exception block instead of SpringUtilException block in Controller.    System.out.println("at line 25 in DAO..");
   employee=null;
   em.persist(employee);
   System.out.println("at line 28 in DAO..");
  } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
   System.out.println("at line 30 in DAO..");
   throw new SpringUtilException(e, "Employee Duplicate");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("at line 33 in DAO..");
      throw new SpringUtilException("Failed to add Employee"); 
  }

Comment: You've already been asked twice to post the stack trace of the exception. And I've explained why you don't get a SpringUtilException in my answer. Read the answers and comments instead of ignoring them.

Comment: at line 25 in DAO..
at line 33 in DAO..
ERROR: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by commit exception
com.kesava.tutorial.util.SpringUtilException
 at com.kesava.tutorial.dao.EmployeeDAO.persist(EmployeeDAO.java:38)
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.